# XMLHttpRequest to another domain

Tags: javascript

What can be done to access remote domain most easily to read data with XML HTTP REQUEST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security restrictions (see the "[Same Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)") it's not possible to make cross-domain requests. Depending on what you need I'd suggest either a custom proxy, an already-existing proxy (e.g. [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)), or [JSONP](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding).

Comment: The good news is that this is now being addressed by the W3C and we can expect recommendations to make their way into browsers fairly quickly; in fact, Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4 already implement the new CORS mechanism:
http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/

Answer (score 0):

The third option is to get them to enable [CSSHTTPRequest](http://ajaxian.com/archives/csshttprequest-cross-domain-ajax-using-css-for-transport).

Answer (score 0):

If you **need** to use an `XHTMLHttpRequest`, make sure the resource being requested sends back an appropriate [Access-Control](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) header. Currently, this will only work in Firefox 3.5 and higher.